# $f$ is measurable iff $|f|$ is $s-$measurable. Show that $S=P(X)$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S)$ be a measurable space such that for every function $f: X \to R$, $f$ is measurable iff $|f|$ is measurable. Show that $S=P(X)$.

It is clear that $S \subset P(X)$. I need to show the other way around. Since I guess that in general if $|f|$ is measurable , then $f$ may not be measurable.I am unable exploit the specialty the reverse condition implies

A hint would suffice

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ has a nonmeasurable subset $E$. Then $f(x) = \chi_E(x) - \chi_{X \setminus E}(x)$ is nonmeasurable, but $|f(x)| = 1$ for all $x$ so that $|f|$ is measurable.

Thus *$f$ measurable if and only if $|f|$ measurable* must imply that $X$ has no nonmeasurable subsets, i.e., $S = P(X)$.